# Accessing call log history in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak, ios4

I gone thro many websites,all provided the same info that we cannot access call_history.db
My question is that can we change the access mode for that db using system('chmod 777 /db path/') command ??

Comment: Think about it.  Would you, as an owner of a telephone like the apps you install on it to be able to access your call log without telling you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least on a non-jailbroken phone.

Answer (score 2):

App store apps run in a sandbox.  You don't have read/write permission to modify those directories from any app running in its sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

why would you want to a have the information of the call list? also why would you want it to change to such liberal permissions?

you don't have root access on the (non-jailbroken)device,
and if you find a way of escalating to root privelages, 
what are the chances of apple allowing it on the appstore?

Comment: Once i have tried for my project and found its illegal..so i droped that idea...anyway thanks for ur kind reply..

Comment: No problem. perhaps if we knew more about what you were trying to accomplish, we could give alternate suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1) Jailbreaking is legal. http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/07/feds-ok-iphone-jailbreaking/

2) Listen to http://icin.ch/3Y9Tc to know why you want to access the call logs.