# How to get call history from iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I try with following code but i can't access it.

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath: @"/private/var/mobile/Library/"];

NSLog(@"DirectoryAttributes:%@",[dirnum directoryAttributes]);
```

Response result :

> "DirectoryAttributes:{
>   NSFileCreationDate = "2008-01-01 05:38:41 GMT";
>   NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
>   NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 501;
>   NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = mobile;
>   NSFileModificationDate = "2011-07-29 11:38:10 GMT";
>   NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
>   NSFileOwnerAccountName = mobile;
>   NSFilePosixPermissions = 493;
>   NSFileReferenceCount = 26;
>   NSFileSize = 986;
>   NSFileSystemFileNumber = 43;
>   NSFileSystemNumber = 234881026;
>   NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;
>   }"

help me to Access call_history.db data table.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone "unable to open database file" for call_history.db  in xcode app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498291/iphone-unable-to-open-database-file-for-call-history-db-in-xcode-app)

Comment: See also [iPhone call log / history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history) and [Accessing call log history in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615240/accessing-call-log-history-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get as -

```
BOOL callhistoryfileexist = FALSE;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


callhistoryfileexist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db"];

[fileManager release];

if(callhistoryfileexist)
{
    //copy it where you want it
}
```

Note : not valid in iOS 5

Comment: @Sulthan if you can see there is already a Note written below answer :)

Comment: @saadnib is it available for iOS 10

Answer (score 5):

Your application is Sandboxed so you can't access any directories outside your App directory. There are no Cocoa Touch or Objective C API's to access the Call Log