# How to get call history in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my application i want last 14 days call history. My Requirement is i only need the last 14 days call number which are not save in my address book.

so please give me some idea how can i get this calls in my application if it possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the calls in the call history of your normal phone application?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all in iOS 5 (using the public APIs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone call log / history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history)

Answer (score 1):

[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996899/how-to-get-call-history-from-iphone) will work in iOS 4, but not iOS 5.  Since your application is sandboxed, it isn't actually allowed to access phone history.  Even if you found a way, it probably would not be allowed into the App Store.  It is not possible in the iOS SDK, unless you jailbreak.

Comment: i already check it and that's why asking if it possible or not bcs there are chance to reject the application.

Comment: It is not possible in the iOS SDK, unless you jailbreak.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for fetching call history and if you use any other method such as accessing the callHistory.db file directly, you will not be able to submit your app to appstore.