# how to delete call table data from call history database

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I am new in iPhone application development. I developing call history  application. I retrieved all the data in call table from call history database. Then now delete all the data in call table from call history database. Please tell me how to delete the all data. please give me some example code link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: means you need to Example of delete all the records from sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

**call_history.db** is a read-only sqlite database, you cannot write to it from an app.

However, even reading from it is something I strongly suggest against. It is a private, undocumented file, and accessing it is liable to get your app rejected. To quote [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656419/how-to-get-call-history-in-iphone):

> There is no public API for fetching call history and if you use any
>   other method such as accessing the callHistory.db file directly, you
>   will not be able to submit your app to appstore.

Thus you would only be able to target jailbroken phones. Also, call_history.db access is broken in 5.0+, so on top of that, you'd be further limited to 4.x and lower.