# Call Log access Possible in ios 8?

Tags: ios, iphone

Can any one say me call log access will be possible in ios 8 or not ?
i want to access all call log in my application from my iphone.
any one know about this ?

Comment: Are you able to find the solution? Is there any way to access call log?

Answer (score 3):

No sorry this still remains as before. Apps are still sandboxed and can't read/write outside of their designated container, so they can't access information from another application if it does it will be rejected for **2.6** of the Apple review process.

> **2.6** Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

As a side note if you were working on jailbroken devices I believe the code from the accepted answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996899/how-to-get-call-history-from-iphone) should work. **Code below copied from link**

```
BOOL callhistoryfileexist = FALSE;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

callhistoryfileexist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db"];

[fileManager release];

if(callhistoryfileexist) {
   //copy it where you want it
}
```

I also just found a project on Github called [SpyPhone](https://github.com/nst/SpyPhone) that might be helpful but again I think this would be jailbroken devices only.

Answer (score 2):

No. Apple will not allow this type of features.

If you make this type of app means. Apple will not approve your Application.

You can only publish for jail Broken Phones via Cydia like this.