# IOS get Call Minutes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, call

is it possible to get all called minutes from my iDevice ? is there an API for example ?
[Here is a link of Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to treat call history db as

> /private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

But it can be rejected by apple. 
Reference: [Call Log access Possible in ios 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638125/call-log-access-possible-in-ios-8)

Comment: so i can't submit it ? Do Apple allowed that ?

Comment: No. If you approach the db data, it will be rejected.
Just it can be used for yourself.

Comment: and it is possible to get the sended SMS ? I only want to get the and number how many SMS's was sended ..

Comment: I am sorry. It looks impossible because of the same reason.